# Can't write data in CSV file using xlsx

Tags: node.js, typescript, xlsx

I'm trying to export read a xlsx file and export it as a readable stream.
I was using the method stream.to_csv. I get the the csv file created but the file is just empty. I think the problem is about the parameter I have put in the method to_csv. I've read the docs but I cant figure out what the method to_scv take as argument. Thank you for your help

```
  const readFile = XLSX.read(path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "users.xlsx"), {
    type: "buffer",
  });
  XLSX.stream
    .to_csv(readFile)
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "users.csv")));
```

Comment: To read a file you should be using `XLSX.readFile` since `XLSX.read` is for reading from a string not from a file.

Comment: I have changed it to XLSX.readFile but I still have the same problem. I have noticed that the type of my variable readFile is XLSX.WorkBook but the method to_csv require an argument of type XLSX.WorkSheet. I don't know where I was doing it wrong

Comment: `XLSX.readFile` returns a workbook which has worksheets. To get the first worksheet use `workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]]`

Answer (score 1):

You could try using XLSX.writeFile() with the bookType set to "csv". Note that this will only export the first sheet:

```
const wb = XLSX.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "users.xlsx"));
XLSX.writeFile(wb, path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "users.csv"),  { bookType: "csv" });
```

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion helped!